strapi filter relational content type
I have a component (named Note) that has a one-to-many relation field to a collection type named Version.
Version has a relation field to collection type App.
Each App has many Notes.
When creating a new Note for an App, in the Version field it shows all contents of type Version but I want to filter it to show just ones that are linked to the same App.
I found that it's possible using custom API that I've to make a custom API which gets the App id in parameters and filters Version(s) that belong to it but cannot find a way to send App id as parameter to custom API.
